# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, error-handling

Getting following exeption:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: C:\Users\OpExWorks\Desktop\Google Chrome    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:148)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)  at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)    at test001.test002.main(test002.java:12)

Code:

```
package test001;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public abstract class test002 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\OpExWorks\\Desktop\\Google Chrome");
        WebDriver w=new ChromeDriver(); 
        w.get("https://www.opexworks.in/Sathi/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The webdriver.chrome.driver has to point to an executable and from the code it looks like you are on Windows. So it should be the path to the .exe file. If the name of the file is "chromedriver.exe" then you should use:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\OpExWorks\\Desktop\\Google Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 35443
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-S3GVH7TL', ip: '192.168.0.104', os.name: 'Windows 10',